# Record as procedure

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to create a record that can be called as a procedure?
Example:

```
Var
  R: TTestRecord;
begin
  R(1);
  // or
  R(1, 'Sametext');
end;
```

I try using operator overloading like this:

```
TProcedure = procedure (const Value: Integer) of object; 

TTestRecord= record
  class operator Implicit(const Value: TTestRecord): TProcedure;
end;
```

But it don't work.

I known what i can using default index property and write like this

```
Var
  R: TTestRecord;
begin
  R[1];
  // or
  R[1, 'Sametext'];
end;
```

But in this case i need always create function with fictitious result and use angle brackets.

Comment: What you want is to call a procedure by name? No Record's work, but I know how to do something using classes and RTTI. If interested I can post.

Comment: I want invoke some method of record using syntax R(1, 'Sametext') because its short and prettily)))). I know std pascal methods like helpers, rtti, procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only hope to make this syntax compile and function would be operator overloading. The operators that can be overloaded are listed here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)

Function call is not among the list of operators that can be overloaded. Thus your desired syntax cannot be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make:

First I created a sample class, but you can use any.

```
type

  TAnyObject = class
    procedure MyMethod;
  end;

implementation

procedure TAnyObject.MyMethod;
begin
  ShowMessage('OK');
end;
```

Now use this function to execute your Procedure.

```
type

  procedure T(var InstantiatedObject: TObject; ProcedureName: String);

implementation

uses Rtti;

procedure T(var InstantiatedObject: TObject; ProcedureName: String);
var
  LRttiContext: TRttiContext;
  LRttiType: TRttiType;
  LRttiMethod: TRttiMethod;
begin
  LRttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    LRttiType := LRttiContext.GetType(InstantiatedObject.ClassType);
    LRttiMethod := LRttiType.GetMethod(ProcedureName);
    LRttiMethod.Invoke(InstantiatedObject,[]);
  finally
    LRttiContext.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Below is an example using this Procedure:

```
var
  LAnyObject : TAnyObject;
begin
  LAnyObject := TAnyObject.Create;

  T(TObject(LAnyObject),'MyMethod');
```

or:

```
var
  LAnyObject : TObject;
begin
  LAnyObject := TAnyObject.Create;

  T(LAnyObject,'MyMethod');
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I thought about using Rtti but for my task it's "thick" solution, because it's slow and using more momery unlike record.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to do `LAnyObject.MyMethod`?

Comment: David, maybe yes, but in this case you could use ``procedure T`` to call any procedure which has the class or another class. The ``TAnyObject`` class is a simple example, another example would be a class where each procedure generates a report, you pass the name (String) and the ``Procedure T`` invokes the correct procedure.